# Crontab Permission Denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, cron, minecraft

I'm having problem with crontab when I'm running a script.

My *sudo crontab -e* looks like this:

```
05 00 * * * /opt/mcserver/backup.sh
10 00 * * * /opt/mcserver/suspend.sh
05 08 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r +1
11 11 * * * /opt/mcserver/start.sh  <--- This isn't working
```

And the *start.sh* looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
screen java -d64 -Xincgc -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

and have these permissions (ls -l output)

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 eve eve  72 Nov 24 14:17 start.sh
```

I can run the command from the terminal, either using sudo or not

```
./start.sh
```

But it wont start with crontab.
If i do

```
grep -iR "start.sh" /var/log
```

I get the following output

```
/var/log/syslog:Nov 27 11:11:01 eve-desk CRON[5204]: (root) CMD (eve /opt/mcserver/start.sh)
grep: /var/log/btmp: Permission denied
grep: /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log: Permission denied
grep: /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log: Permission denied
grep: /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log: Permission denied
```

So my question is, why isn't it working? 
And since my script run without using sudo, I don't necessarily need to put it in sudo crontab?

*( and I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 )*

Thanks in advance,
Philip

---

*Answer to twalberg's response*

**1.** Changed owner on craftbukkit to root, to see if that fixed the problem.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12084211 Nov 21 02:14 craftbukkit.jar
```

and also added an explicit cd in my start.sh script as such:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /opt/mcserver/
screen java -d64 -Xincgc -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

**2.** I'm not quite sure what you mean here. Should I use the following path in my start.sh file when i start java?
(*output from which java*)

```
/usr/bin/java
```

**3.** When my server closes, screen is terminated. Is it a good idea to start screen in "detached mode" anyway?

Still got the same "Permission denied" error.

---

**Problem solved**!
By using the proper flag on screen, as below, it is now working as it should!

```
screen -d -m java -d64 -Xincgc -Xmx2048M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

*Thanks a lot to those who answered, and especially twalberg!*

Comment: On #2 - using `/usr/bin/java` should be fine if that's the one you usually use (by just typing `java`) - I didn't know for sure though whether you used a different location, so I didn't suggest a specific path. For #3, I've never tried starting `screen` without a controlling terminal available, so I suggested that possibility - not sure if it's necessary, but worth trying. And the "Permission denied" is coming from `grep` not being able to read those files - not from your `cron` job failing in any way. Is `cron` e-mailing any output from the script?

Comment: I (stupidly) didnt set up croncab to send me e-mail. 
But now when I did, i got this:
Must be connected to a terminal.

So I guess the problew has to do with screen?

Comment: And now it works! The problem had to do with not using _screen -d -m_ in my script!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some things to check:

1. `root` obviously has read/execute permissions on `start.sh`, but what are the permissions on `craftbukkit.jar` - can `root` read it? You may also want to add an explicit `cd /path/to/where/craftbukkit.jar/is` in your `start.sh` script.
2. Is `java` in `root`'s default path within `cron`? Note that this path is not necessarily the same as the one that you get via `sudo`, `su` or directly logging in as root - it's typically much more restricted. Use full path names to both `java` and `craftbukkit.jar` to work around that.
3. Since `screen` will not start with a terminal available, you may need `screen -d -m ...` instead. Hopefully, you intend to eventually attach to each `screen` instance and terminate it later, or you have arranged for it to terminate automatically when the script is done...
4. The `/var/log/syslog` entry shows that `cron` did in fact execute the script, so it must have failed for one of the above reasons (or something else I haven't noticed yet)
5. The other errors from `grep` are simply due to the fact your non-`root` user does not have permission to read those specific files (this is normal, and a good thing).

Comment: Added response above, due to better formatting possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

`start.sh` is owned by "eve:eve" and your crontab is running as root.

You can solve this by running following command

```
chown root:root /opt/craftbukkit/start.sh
```

Your crontab will be running as root though.

**Tip:** When running bash in crontab always use absolute paths (it will make debugging a lot easier).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this didn't help. 
/var/log/syslog:Nov 27 11:41:01 eve-desk CRON[5445]: (root) CMD (/opt/mcserver/start.sh)
grep: /var/log/btmp: Permission denied
grep: /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log: Permission denied
grep: /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log: Permission denied
grep: /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log: Permission denied

Changed the owner to:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 72 Nov 24 14:17 start.sh

Comment: Not really relevant, as `root` has permission to read and execute `start.sh` (although we don't know what the permissions are on, e.g. `craftbukkit.jar` and any other files that `root` will eventually need to touch as a result of running `start.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

The log shows the user has no access to dir " /var/log/", You should set the log files' permition for the cron's owner.

Comment: Why doesn't _sudo crontab_ have acces to these /var/log files? And how/ (and should) I change them?